# Sum of coloumn based on two condition in where cluase

Tags: sql-server

I have table structure

```
ACNo    Deal    PRODTYPE    INT AMT
100     123     OS           23
100     123     EX            7
```

I have to group by Deal,AC NO and have to report other column as well, but for Int amount have to do sum of for both prod type.
How I can implement it?

Result

```
AC No   Deal        Total INT   
100     123             30
```

Answer (score 1):

something like this ?

```
select  ACNo, 
        Deal, 
        sum([INT AMT]) as [Total INT]
from    unknowntablename
group by ACNo, Deal
```

You can test this like this :

```
declare @table table (ACNo int, Deal int, PRODTYPE varchar(2), [INT AMT] int)

insert into @table values (100, 123, 'OS', 23)
insert into @table values (100, 123, 'EX', 7)

select  ACNo, 
        Deal, 
        sum([INT AMT]) as [Total INT]
from    @table
group by ACNo, Deal
```

the outcome will be :

```
ACNo   Deal   Total INT
100    123    30
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT AccNo, DEAL, SUM([INT AMT]) AS Total Amount
FROM Table
GROUP BY AccNo, DEAL
```